# How does resp.Body implements the Read function?

Tags: go, interface, go-interface

I'm currently studying Go and trying to understand the concept of Interfaces.
What I understand about it is that whatever type implements the functions specified in the interface is part of it.
My question is about the Body of type io.ReadCloser inside of the Response struct. How does it implement the Read function? I've searched through the documentation and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`io.ReadCloser` does not implement the `Read` function. `io.ReadCloser` is an interface type, so it by itself cannot implement any methods. However, an interface `T` can implement another interface `I` if `T`'s *type set* is a *subset* of `I`.

---

The `io.ReadCloser` interface embeds the `io.Reader` and `io.Closer` interfaces. Therefore the method set of `io.ReadeCloser` is the combined method set of `io.Reader` and `io.Closer`.

Thanks to [embedding](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Embedded_interfaces) the type set of `io.ReadCloser` is the intersection of `io.Reader`'s and `io.Closer`'s type sets. In other words the type set of `io.ReadCloser` is the set of all types that implement the `io.Reader` and `io.Closer` interfaces.

The above also means that the type set of `io.ReadCloser` is a subset of `io.Reader`'s type set and `io.Closer`'s type set.

The `io.ReadCloser` interface [implements](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Implementing_an_interface) `io.Reader` because:

> A type T implements an interface I if
>
> - T is not an interface and is an element of the type set of I; or
> - **T is an interface and the type set of T is a subset of the type set of I.**